# Striked out functions

Tags: java, jasper-reports

Why is ***`JasperManager.loadXmlDesign()`*** crossed out?  It still works but just wanted to know what's the deal is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This means the method is Deprecated. Use `JRXmlLoader.load(InputStream)` instead.

See the [Jasper documentation](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JasperManager.html). Typically, as a library evolves, the developers will decide to deprecate some methods and approaches. But, to maintain backwards compatibility, they might leave the methods there for a couple of versions.

It is recommended that you don't use deprecated methods, since they might be removed in future versions, and also often because there are better alternatives.